# Grep the URL's embedded in XML file

Tags: sed, grep

I'm trying to grep/sed from the following xml data:

```
<record 
address="11.800.96.10" name="_ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.example.com" port="3268" target="aws-sit2.example.com" type="SRV"/>
```

I wanted to retrieve below information in below format:

> address value, name value, port value

Each record will have a carriage return after one liner recorded values extracted. How do I achieve this?

Comment: How have you attempted to solve this problem on your own? Please include any relevant commands in your question.

Answer (score 1):

For parsing XML, use an xml parser, e.g. [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)!

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//record' \
  -v '@address' -o " " \
  -v '@name' -o " " \
  -v '@port' -n \
xmlfile
```

Change the separator after `-o` to your needs. Or use `-n` for newline.

Comment: This doesn't make use of either `sed`, nor `grep`.

Comment: Using `sed` and/or `grep` is a really bad idea for parsing xml data.

Comment: In general I would agree, and maybe you should include this in your answer; but no mention is made of how this will be utilized.

Answer (score 0):

`awk '{print $1", "$2", "$3}' | sed -e 's/[=]/ /g' -e 's/["]//g'`
This should work fine